# VM on GCP keeps shutting down for no reason

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine

this is my first time to build a Wordpress on GCP and host it
everything is good except the server gets shut down occasionally
I have no idea where it could go wrong
coz the problem is solved when I pick a higher tier of machine type instead of shared core
but the cost would be unaffordable

in today morning
the server is down again like below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRSBH.png)

however, when I go to my GCP
it said the Wordpress is good and running
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4jcB.png)

below is the only warning that I have found
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIRAm.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v52dl.png)

been trying to fix it but no clue

below is the website I hosted
https://decostationhk.com

Comment: Showing `Error establishing a database connection` error

Comment: this is the first time I see this error message
it used to be 404
but what I can do except reboot the VM

Comment: Check the database name, username and password are correct in wp-config.php